# 6 Windows 10 Black screen and white line

Tags: windows-10

After Windows 10 restarted due to an update on 3/16/17, now all I'm getting is a black screen with a blinking white line. I've tried removing all unessential cords. I've also tried unplugging the power cord, holding power button for 30 seconds, unplugging and plugging back in the HD. None of these worked.

Comment: It's just a white horizontal blinking line (nothing else) and I'm unable to type anything other than ctrl-alt-del which reboots my computer and returns to the same screen.

Comment: create a new user profile as suggested on reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/5zdwlb/march_windows_10_cumulative_updates_are_out/ last update can corrupt profiles

Comment: I can't get to that part. When I boot my computer it just shows me my motherboard logo with the option to choose boot options with <DEL> or motherboard settings with <F11>, then the black screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try booting into Safe Mode. This can be hard to do with Windows 10, so another option is to boot to a Windows 10 CD (or flash drive). Either way, the goal is to use System Restore to roll your system settings back.